# JQuery - merging after removing middle element

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose my HTML looks like this

```
<p>a<span>b</span>c</p>
```

after

```
$("span").remove();
```

my HTML looks like this

```
<p>
"a"
"c"
</p>
```

how do I merge those two parts together, so my HTML looks like `<p>ac</p>`?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgBwc/12/)

Comment: Why are you so fixated on that?

Comment: Call it a combination of OCD and curiosity :)

Comment: I'll give the best answer ever -> `$(p).html('ac');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("span").remove();
$("p").html($("p").html());
​
```

Result:

```
<p>ac</p>
```

Comment: Well that was... annoyingly simple.

Comment: I believe all children nodes' bindings will be gone. Sorry, it can't be that easy

Comment: @Alexander that _is_ a limitation. Normally, there won't be direct bindings, though (especially when event delegation is sooo easy).

Comment: @JanDvorak, I can't second that

Answer (score 0):

Here is one, it only affects text nodes joining any two consecutive ones.

```
$("span").click(function() {
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    $(this).remove();
    normalize(parent);
});
function normalize(element){
    var contents = $(element).contents();
    contents.each(function(i){console.log(this.nodeType);
        if (this.nodeType == 3 && i > 0){
            var prev = contents[i-1];
            if (prev.nodeType == 3){
                this.nodeValue += prev.nodeValue;
                prev.parentNode.removeChild(prev);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/dgBwc/13/

Answer (score 0):

```
var p  = $('p'),
    p2 = p.clone(true);
    p2.find('span').remove();
    p2.text(p2.text());
    p.parent().empty().append(p2);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JpvyX/7/)

Keeps bindings!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this is what [`Node.normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) is for:

```
$('p').get(0).normalize()
```

> The Node.normalize() method puts the specified node and all of its sub-tree into a "normalized" form. In a normalized sub-tree, no text nodes in the sub-tree are empty and there are no adjacent text nodes.